# Using popen, but text looks weird - Python

Tags: python, command-line, popen

I'm using os.popen() in order to run a few commands.

This is what **"man ls"** looks like:

[image]

---

Any ideas why the text is displayed as such. I tried both Arial and Consolas fonts.

Help would be amazing! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are backspace characters: `man` is trying to backspace and reprint characters to get bolding, or underscores plus backspaces to get underlining.

The `man` man page says:

> To get a plain text version of a man page, without backspaces and underscores, try
>
> `#` man foo | col -b > foo.mantxt

You could also do a simple post-processing in Python:

```
s = re.sub(".\x08", "", s)
```

This removes any pair of characters where the second character is a backspace.

Comment: thanks that was an awesome answer =D I'm going to try and capture the backspaces and bold the characters somehow

Comment: came to write that re.sub() in the questions! Thanks you so much Ned! Mission accomplished =)